# Optimizing SVD factors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

## Problem Description

My aim is to find the SVD decomposition of the minimizer of $F:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\to\mathbb{R}$
$$
U_*\Sigma_* V^\top_* = A_*\qquad \text{where} \qquad A_* = \arg\min_A F(A)
$$
I could, of course, just minimize $F(\cdot)$ and then compute the SVD decomposition. However, I am interested in finding the optimal SVD decomposition directly. Is this possible?
For instance, one way to go about it would be this:

1. Initialize $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and compute its SVD decomposition $A = U\Sigma V^\top$.
2. For $i = 1, \ldots, n$ iterations do:

   3. Keep $\Sigma V^\top$ fixed and optimize $F(\cdot)$ with respect to $U\in\mathcal{V}_r(\mathbb{R}^m) = \{U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times r}\,:\,U^\top U = I\}$ on the space of orthogonal matrices.
   4. Keep $U\Sigma$ fixed and optimize $F(\cdot)$ with respect to $V\in\mathcal{V}_r(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{\mathbb{V}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}\,:\, V^\top V = I\}$ on the space of orthogonal matrices.
   5. Keep $U$ and $V$ fixed and optimize $F(\cdot)$ with respect to $\Sigma = \text{diag}(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_r)$

Is it possible to construct a "coordinate-descent"-type algorithm that would do something like this? Of course the algorithm above is very likely to fail because most likely $U$, $\Sigma$ and $V$ won't give rise to a good matrix $A=U\Sigma V^\top$.

## Resources

Optimization in the space of orthogonal matrices is generally doable, for instance one can use [this](https://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/102167/TR10-26.PDF;jsessionid=25D8C420B4DF121F0B551BB85D42C131?sequence=1) paper.

Comment: There is a telling discrepancy between your problem description and your example algorithm, namely the presence of the constant $r$. Is the goal here to find a minimizer of prescribed rank $r$? If so, then this could very well be a good way to approach the problem.

Comment: If the rank constraint is not the point, then an alternative approach that you might want to consider is to use the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition)
$$
A = P U
$$
where $P$ is constrained to be symmetric and $U$ is constrained to be orthogonal.

Comment: Another approach that is used (particularly in the context of [NMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization)) is to use the factorization $A = BC$ where $B$ has size $m \times r$ and $C$ has size $r \times n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think you have a good point. Technically my goal is to solve
$$
\min_{A} F(A) \qquad \qquad \text{such that} \quad \text{rank}(A) \leq r
$$
In other words, I don't know the optimal rank.  However, while reasoning about this problem, I realised that *maybe* I could consider $r$ to be a hyperparameter and optimize that in an outer loop somehow.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Also, in my post I said SVD but I was actually referring to Compact SVD: there aren't any $0$-valued diagonal entries in $\Sigma$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for suggesting these approaches. I am a bit confused, what is the difference of using the polar decomposition? Is it because we don't need to know the rank? 

I thought the polar decomposition, given the compact SVD was basically a rewriting of the SVD as
$$
A = U \Sigma V^\top = (U V^\top) (V\Sigma V^\top)
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I would really appreciate it if you could help me navigate some of these options for fixed or variable rank. As I said my original problem has constraint $\text{rank}(A)\leq r$. But if this is too infeasible, then I am happy to consider solutions for a fixed rank.

Comment: Typically, if you give an upper bound to the rank, it is highly unlikely that you "accidentally" end up with a smaller rank than your specified upper bound, so it is much more common to do things that way

Comment: The main difference with polar decomposition in this context is that instead of optimizing over $3$ matrix parameters, you're optimizing over two matrix parameters, hence there is perhaps "less to worry about".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach.

Since you're looking for a "descent" type algorithm, I'll assume that $F$ is a differentiable function. Let $\Phi(X)$ denote the [denominator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Denominator-layout_notation) derivative of $F$ (so the $i,j$ entry of $\Phi$ is the derivative of $F$ with respect to the $i,j$ entry of $X$).

- The gradient (i.e. denominator layout derivative) of $F$ with respect to $U$ is given by the product $\Phi(U \Sigma V^T) V \Sigma^T$. To update $U$, you could apply the method in the paper you linked.
- The gradient of $F$ with respect to $\Sigma$ is given by $VU^T\Phi(U \Sigma V^T)$.  Update the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ using the diagonal entries of this gradient
- The gradient of $F$ with respect to $V$ is given by $\Phi^T(U\Sigma V^T)U \Sigma $. Again, use the method in the paper you linked.

---

The derivative of $F$ with respect to $U$:

I find it easiest to first obtain these derivatives in [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form).  With that said, we have
$$
\begin{align}
F((U + dU) \Sigma V^T) = F(U \Sigma V^T) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(U\Sigma V^T)(dU \,\Sigma V^T) + o(\|dU\|).
\end{align}
$$
here, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}$ is a function that takes an $m \times n$ matrix as its input and produces a linear function from $\Bbb R^{m\times n} \to \Bbb R$. Notably, $\Phi = \Phi(X)$ is defined such that
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(X)(H) = \operatorname{tr}(\Phi^TH).
$$
With that, we can rewrite the above as
$$
\begin{align}
F((U + dU) \Sigma V^T) &= F(U \Sigma V^T) + \operatorname{tr}(\Phi^T \cdot dU \,\Sigma V^T)
+ o(\|dU\|)
\\ &= 
F(U \Sigma V^T) + \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma V^T \Phi^T \cdot dU) + o(\|dU\|)
\\ & = 
F(U \Sigma V^T) + \operatorname{tr}((\Phi V \Sigma^T)^T \cdot dU) + o(\|dU\|).
\end{align}
$$
With that, we can conclude that the denominator layout derivative of $F$ with respect to $U$ is $\Phi V \Sigma^T$.

Comment: Thank you, that looks good! One thing I thought about is that the rotation given by V and the one given by U need to be "synched" in order to make sense. Hence I was thinking that perhaps I could concatenate the two matrices vertically to obtain $W = [U; V]$ which is a matrix in $(m+n)\times r$. Do you think this would make sense? The aim would be to update both at the same time

Comment: That’s an interesting thought, but I don’t see how $W$ could be updated in a way that preserves the structure of both $U$ and $V$. One argument for working with the polar decomposition is that there is only one orthogonal matrix to work with, so arguably this “synching” happens automatically by design.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! In your writing would $\Phi(U\Sigma V^\top)$ essentially be $G = \frac{\partial F}{\partial X_{ij}}$ defined in the paper? I am quite new to differential geometry

Comment: Yes, that’s right, where $X=U\Sigma V^T.$

Comment: Thanks! How did you find those derivative expressions? I know that $\partial_U F(U, \Sigma, V) = (\partial_X F) \partial_U X$ by the chain rule but not sure how you go about finding $\partial_U X$, $\partial_V X$ and $\partial_{\Sigma} X$. My attempt was 
$$
\partial_U X = \partial_U (U\Sigma V^\top) = (\partial_U U)(\Sigma V^\top) + U(\partial_U \Sigma V^\top) = \Sigma V^\top
$$
But you seem to get the transpose of this

Comment: And similar for $\Sigma$ or $V$
$$
\nabla_{\Sigma} X = \nabla_{\Sigma}(U\Sigma V^\top) = (\partial_{\Sigma} U)(\Sigma V^\top) + U(\partial_{\Sigma} \Sigma V^\top) = U[V^\top + 0] = UV^\top
$$

Comment: I suspect that what you are finding is the [numerator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Numerator-layout_notation) derivative, which is indeed the transpose of the denominator layout derivative (which I have calculated). Denominator layout derivatives are better suited to gradient descent since they point in the direction of greatest increase.

Comment: I am also a bit confused by the dimensions. The function to optimize is $F:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\to\mathbb{R}$ meaning the Jacobian will be $J_X F\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times(m\times n)}$ and the gradient will be its transpose $\nabla_X F\in\mathbb{R}^{(m\times n)\times 1}$. However $V\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$. Then the dimensions don't match

Comment: Oh makes sense! I will look into the different layouts!

Comment: I'll add a detailed derivation of one of the derivatives.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Thank you so much! Will have a look